# Philosophical quest set in a very dark desert

Tags: story-identification

I think it aired on PBS in the early nineties.  It might have been a foreign film.

The main characters were kids or young adults.  The setting was post-apocalyptic and may have possibly been purgatory.

There was a scene in a very dark desert area, with the kids hiding behind a mound as robed figures passed by.

There were little to no special effects.

The movie seemed very philosophical as the goal of the quest was to reach Heaven.  The movie is not "The Lathe of Heaven."

At the end, a young girl walks into a clean space (possibly a shop) with a fountain and lots of plants and is reunited with someone.

Comment: Was it heaven as in literal Heaven (angels and harps, etc) or heaven as in a place of sanctuary in an otherwise crappy world?

Comment: Do you clearly remember that the whole movie was set in this post-apocalyptic-style realm or is it possible that it was just a few memorable scenes?

Comment: Excellent questions. No it was a stylized, rather than literal, heaven. I think it was probably shot over-exposed, with lots of lighting, a gauzy feel to the cinematography. No angels, but the few characters in the scene were dressed in light colored clothing. At this distance of time, it's possible that I'm remembering only one or a few particular scenes. However, I remember clearly thinking that the movie had really created an immersive environment, with seemingly minimal sets and special effects.

Comment: I think that it could be Eden log

Comment: @libathos:
Based on the Wikipedia entry, I don't see any sort of a match.

Comment: @libathos Eden Log was a few decades later. This aired in the early nineties.